# Ajax does not return the value from php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, typo3

I am using this code in my JavaScript file to get a value from my php script.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/home/example.com/ftp/www/typo3conf/ext/quiz_rs/pi1',
    data: 'end_of_quiz=1',
    success: function(data){
        alert('successful'); // I am getting this message
        $('.end_of_quiz').text(data);
    }
});
```

In my php file (which is a typo3 plugin) I am using this code:

```
if (isset($_POST['end_of_quiz'])) {
    echo 'I am a nice text. Let me out of here!';
    die;
}
```

The output is the HTML source of the whole page and *null*.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why you giving full path ?

Comment: you're sending a get request and checking for a post variable. what could possibly be wrong here. hmmmmmmmm

Comment: That's normal, TYPO3 returns default HTML doc with head, body etc, which version of TYPO3 are you using? I can see an old-school `pi1`, really?

Answer (score 0):

You're using `$_POST` to retrieve the value, yet sending a GET request. You either need to change `$_POST` to `$_GET` in the PHP code, or `type: 'POST'` to `type: 'GET'` in the jQuery `$.ajax` method options.

Comment: Thanks, I have changed this but I still keep getting the same output.